# Bootstrap v4 toggle drop-down menu not working locally, but works on public site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

For most of today I can't get my bootstrap v4 collapsable hamburger menu to work on my local xampp server.  Strangely, it works just fine on my [public website](http://www.stephengladwin.com)!  The hamburger appears at 768 px wide display.  This is problem is present in Chrome and Firefox.

I'm at a loss.  I've combed through similar stackoverflow threads but haven't found anything that addresses my problem.  My navbar code block is also identical to the navbar example in the Bootstrap class on lynda.com.

I know this much:

I am using the latest minified version of jquery, and the order of the javascript script files in the "head" section of my xampp/local "index.html" doc is identical to the one in my hosted/public server index.html file.  Here's a difference that may or may not matter: I use CDN links to access all bootstrap files for my public/hosted page, and use relative link paths to access the JS/CSS files on my computer for my XAMPP/local website ("htdocs" is the root folder for my xampp setup).

To rule out some things, I copy/pasted the nav bar code block from my public page (the code that makes the hamburger icon expand upon click) into my local index.html file which is hosted on xampp.  No joy.  I know the relative folder paths are correct for the javascript files in my local xampp server (htdocs is the root folder, and the JS files are in the "js" folder).

I also tried re-downloading the newest version of jQuery (3.2.1) into my local folder thinking maybe the file I was using was corrupted, but still nothing.  I'm assuming the hamburger menu functionality is a jQuery thing, but perhaps it's javascript.

Finally: I checked the console for my local "index.html" page and there were no errors.

So what gives?  Why isn't my hamburger menu working on my local production server but works fine on my public page?  Does it have to do with the javascript files being loaded via CDN vs locally on my hard drive?

Please see below my head and nav bar code block for my local production/xampp server (this is the code that doesn't work) and then the code block for my head and nav bar (this is the code that does work).  I think the problem lies in the "head" section and how js is linked/accessed.

Thanks for any help!

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-US-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <meta content="Steve Gladwin" name="description"/>
    <meta content="portfolio, design, steve, steven, stephen, systems, librarian, social media, library," name="keywords"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

 
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">

     <!-- Local CSS File -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" media="screen">
    <title>Steve Gladwin</title>


 
    <!-- Bootstrap Javascript/jQuery -->
    <script src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

     <!-- Bootstrap JS Tether -->

   <script src="/js/tether.min.js"</script>

   <!-- Bootstrap JS -->

   <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>





    

</head>


<body>

  <!-- <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"> -->
    
         <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-toggleable-sm" style="background-color: red;">
          <!-- <div class="container"> -->

          <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#burgercollapse" aria-controls="burgercollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

            <h1 class="navbar-brand mr-auto">Steve Gladwin</h1>
          <!--   </div> -->


          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="burgercollapse">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Resume</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">For Fun</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Social</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div> <!--collpase-->


          </nav>
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-US-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <meta content="Steve Gladwin" name="description"/>
    <meta content="portfolio, design, steve, steven, stephen, systems, librarian, social media, library," name="keywords"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Bootstrap Javascript/jQuery -->
   <!--  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    <!-- script src="css/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist/tether-1.3.3/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script> -->
<!-- <script src="css/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script> -->





<!--<script src="css/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>-->
    <!-- <link href="css/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
    <!-- <link href="css/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css" media="screen">
    <title>Steve Gladwin</title>
</head>


<body>

  <!-- <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Steve Gladwin</h2>
      </div> -->
      
   <!--    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"> -->
    
         <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-toggleable-sm" style="background-color: red;">
          <!-- <div class="container"> -->

          <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#burgercollapse" aria-controls="burgercollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

            <h1 class="navbar-brand mr-auto">Steve Gladwin</h1>
          <!--   </div> -->


          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="burgercollapse">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Resume</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">For Fun</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Social</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div> <!--collpase-->


          </nav>
```

Comment: Step 1: Have you re-downloaded the Bootstrap .css and .js files? Step 2: Have you tried using CDN instead of local files in your local version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your markup on the 1st code block is malformed

```
<script src="/js/tether.min.js"</script>
```

you're missing the closing `>`

You reference CDNs in your other code block also and relative files on your local version. Be sure that they are referenced correctly.

Comment: And this is why I love Stackoverflow!  I would have never caught this on my own.  That little closing > was the thing that fixed it.  Amazing.  Thank you!